# Commentig Eclipse Projects

Tags: eclipse

Maybe I just need new glasses, and I'm missing something the the menus ? 
Is there a way to add comments to an ECLIPSE PROJECT? - Not comments in the source code, or resources, but comments on the project itself.

Comment: Not by standard, but it's Eclipse: *There's a plugin for That* (TM). To clarify: I don't know any particular 'though.

Comment: How about adding a README file to the root? Bonus points: you'll be able to read the documentation without Eclipse.

Comment: How would you add comments if Eclipse wasn't a factor?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks much for the answer. Since The TerribleSwiftTomato answered 1st, I'd accept that as an answer if you want to re-post it and say "No you can't..."